# ¿La expresión "sí o sí" va siempre entre comas?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, locuciones, redacción

Si se intercala ese sí o sí entre una o varias oraciones, ¿siempre tiene que ir entre comas?

Por ejemplo:

> Mis amigos, sí o sí, están esperándome para ir al partido.

Yo lo veo como un conector del tipo: "en definitiva".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sí o sí" significa "sin duda", y es por tanto una locución adverbial **modalizadora** (véanse [§30.11a y §30.11b](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuwkLxdJiThNHXot) de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española (NGLE)). Las locuciones adverbiales modalizadoras que expresan necesidad, imposición u obligación se llaman *deónticas*, y se tratan en el [§30.11m](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuwkgrOkOgmIcIg,) de la NGLE, que pone como ejemplos los siguientes:

> *necesariamente, obligatoriamente, indefectiblemente, con seguridad [...], de todas todas [...]*

Aunque no está mencionado explícitamente, es razonable pensar que "sí o sí" pertenece a esta lista. El §30.11m pone algunos ejemplos de oraciones con estos adverbios:

> Se van **sin remedio** [...]. Son blues, valses, canciones dulzonas en que el leitmotiv es –**indefectiblemente**– el cielo azul de la noche. [...] obedeciendo al principio de que si las cosas han de ser **obligatoriamente** de una cierta manera no pueden ser de otra [...]

Todas las locuciones en **negrita** se pueden sustituir por **sí o sí**, por lo que que no es necesario separar la expresión "sí o sí" con comas siempre. Como los otros ejemplos, puede funcionar sintácticamente como un complemento del verbo:

- Me estarán esperando sí o sí
- Esta tiene que ser sí o sí la ultima vez

o como un inciso, separado por comas (o rayas, como en el ejemplo de la NGLE):

- Esta noticia, sí o sí, provocará una reacción fuerte.
- Mañana nevará, sí o sí.

Entiendo que el uso de las comas sirve para enfatizar la seguridad que tiene el hablante, aunque esto no está mencionado en la NGLE.